# How can you combine multiple graphs and control with one range selector with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple graphs one on page. The goal with these charts is to sync the charts up to one range selector (preferably a custom one which allow for predefined time selections ~1day, ~7days, ~30days etc). Something which is similar to that of Grafana and it's layout.

Imagine the following layout

```
---- Range Selector ----
||||||||||||||||||||||||
------- Graph 1 --------
||||||||||||||||||||||||
------- Graph 2 --------
```

I have scoured Highcharts forums for an answer and within the documentation and have not found anything other than to make use of `master-detail` [API Reference](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail)

If anyone has attempted anything similar, or seen another framework which could better help in the direction I wish to take, it would be appreciated for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to connect the navigator range with x-axes extremes by using `setExtremes` method. The below example is using a navigator from Highstock.

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, true, false);
                chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, true, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4Lfegyqa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes